# How to change RGB configuration of an image in Flutter

Tags: image, image-processing, flutter, dart

I want to put a color filter over an asset image.
As below, I currently have an image with colorBlendMode filter, but I want to be able to directly fix the RGB value of each pixel of the image. 
Does anyone know how this can be done?

```
body: Center(
        child: new Image.asset(
          'assets/gallery/garrowby_hill.jpg',
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(redCount, greenCount, blueCount, 1),
          colorBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **ColorFiltered class** and use your image as it's child and use **colorFilter property** ,
***TODO*:**

1. Wrap your **Image.asset** in a new Widget called **ColorFiltered**
2. add a new property for this widget : colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(**your_color_here**, BlendeMode.**your_blendMode_here**).

You can check those links : [ColorFilter Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter-class.html), [colorFilter propery](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ColorFiltered/colorFilter.html) and [it's used in this video](https://youtu.be/6KiPEqzJIKQ)